# Use github or other to push to another repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

In order to publish what I need, my server service gave me a git repository in which I push my files.

The issue is: I can push to GitHub and BitBucket without issues from my workplace, but this server-git address is blocked. Unblocking it is not an option.

I have an exact copy of that repo in private BitBucket, so when I need to do maintenance I do it at work, push to BitBucket, get home, pull, copy to the other repo, push to the server. Sometimes I have to wait all day to push my changes to production, at home.

Is there a way to push to BitBucket (or GitHub, or else) and, in the background, some process push the data to my other repo?

Is there a way to do this?

Instead of: `WORK -> SERVER`

I'd like to: `WORK -> (SOME SERVICE) -> SERVER`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Github push to a remote server when it receives updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196304/make-github-push-to-a-remote-server-when-it-receives-updates)

Comment: @AdilB it looks like a similar question but different variables. In my case, I don't have access to the remote server entirely to issue commands like git pull from another repo. I dunno if I'm being entirely clear, the nomenclature is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are you only able to push to the remote server, but unable to tell it to pull from elsewhere?